# jquery start time /end time validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I need to validate the start time and end time . I seems to be got the validation to work partially , but when there is not value for both then I need not to validate , so make it not required.

```
$.validator.addMethod("endTimeRange", function() {
        var n=new Date();
        var st = Date.parse( n.getMonth()+1+'/'+n.getDate()+'/'+n.getFullYear() + ' ' + $("#startTime").val());
        var nd = Date.parse( n.getMonth()+1+'/'+n.getDate()+'/'+n.getFullYear() + ' ' + $("#endTime").val());
        return  nd > st;
    }, "Please specify a correct end time, the end time must be before the second.");

    $.validator.addMethod("startTimeRange", function() {
        var n=new Date();
        var st = Date.parse( n.getMonth()+1+'/'+n.getDate()+'/'+n.getFullYear() + ' ' + $("#startTime").val());
        var nd = Date.parse( n.getMonth()+1+'/'+n.getDate()+'/'+n.getFullYear() + ' ' + $("#endTime").val());
        return  st < nd;
    }, "Please specify a correct start time, the start time must be after the end time.");


startTime: {
             required: function(element) {
             return $("#endTime").val().length > 0;

            },
            startTimeRange:true
        },

        endTime: {
             required: function(element) {
             return $("#startTime").val().length > 0;
            },
            endTimeRange:true

        },
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your two validation methods do the same thing. To implement successful validation if one or both of the fields are empty, just add them to your return:

```
// default is true
var isValid = true;

// if either value is empty, dont validate
if ($("#endTime").val() !== '' && $("#startTime").val() !== '') {
    // start time must be before end time
    isValid = startTime <= endTime;
}

return isValid;
```

Comment: How would i incorporate what I've got with your suggestion

Comment: you're approaching the "can you do my job for me?" point, i would suggest you spend more time trying to get it working.

Comment: I've change the function to this it validates but little bit not correct. so when i select an end time it still show the error message

Comment: $.validator.addMethod("dateRange", function() {
  var n=new Date();
  var st = Date.parse( n.getMonth()+1+'/'+n.getDate()+'/'+n.getFullYear() + ' ' + $("#startTime").val());
  var nd = Date.parse( n.getMonth()+1+'/'+n.getDate()+'/'+n.getFullYear() + ' ' + $("#endTime").val());
  var isValid = true;
  //alert('1t' + st);
 // alert('2t' + nd);
  if ($("#endTime").val() !== '' && $("#startTime").val() !== '') {
   isValid = nd > st;
  }

  return  isValid;
 }, "Please specify valid time");